# Activities back stack seems to be lost

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, activity-finish

I have 2 activities: A and B
In B, I have a back arrow to go back to A by calling "finish()" method.
It works fine, except when the following is done:

- I go to B
- I put my app in background
- I restore my app from "recent apps"
- I press the back arrow, and then, the app is finished instead of going back to activity A.

Any help please ?

Comment: Hi..Can you share your code that u r trying?

Comment: Don't use launch mode in your manifest/java file.

Comment: Exactly.  I tried a test project and it seems to be related to the launchMode="singleInstance".  I am working on it to see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve this:
As @Karthikeyan mentioned in its comment, setting launchMode to "singleInstance" is cause of the problem. I changed it to "singleTask" and it worked fine.
In fact, according to the google doc stated in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack,

> "singleInstance".
>       Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance.

So logically, with "singleInstance", the activity when restored from the background had no other activity in the same back stack, and thus, calling finish() would simply finish the activity without restoring whatsoever (the very first activity is in the background and in another separate task)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not keep activities** make sure that this option is not enabled in your device's developer settings.

Comment: It is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

> Set flag in onStop () method to know and write condition onBackPress () condition to navigate to A according to the Flag value changes

Answer (score 0):

Make Activity A as parent Activity of Activity B in your manifest file. Works for you.